# How to check that `undertow-handlers.conf` is read/used?

Tags: jboss, undertow, samesite

I have a Jboss 7.4.
I added into my war application a `undertow-handlers.conf` file in the WEB-INF folder.
Content is :

```
path(/)->samesite-cookie(mode=LAX, case-sensitive=false, enable-client-checker=false, add-secure-for-none=false)
```

But I can not see anything in the logs when Jboss is starting about that file. Except when the syntax of the file is not correct.
Is there a setting I can change to see if that handler is set and read/used?

Actually, setting LAX using this method for Samesite is not working at all and I wonder if this file is currently used/read at start.

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting the following line at the top of `undertow-handlers.conf`:

```
dump-request
```

Then hit any URL on your JBoss and check your server log.

As a less verbose alternative, you can also print some of the variables available to the access log

```
access-log(format='%m; %U; %R')
```

When trying to match paths using, say, path-prefix then the %R relative path is what you want to match on. To test that the match works, you can combine a match with some output, e.g. the following would be expected to dump the verbose debug info for your spongebob API but not for any other path.

```
path-prefix('/api/spongebob') -> dump-request
```

I'm mentioning the above because matching paths has been a major source of headaches for me until I figured out how to dump the access log variables. And matching paths is pretty much the core functionality of Undertow.

The documentation is pretty hard to find but this is the best resource that I know of: https://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-2.0.0/predicates-attributes-handlers.html